# os.chdir() is not working in mac

Tags: python, macos, chdir

I am writing a python script to take user input and create directory and change to new directory. However when I invoke os.chdir() and os.getcwd() doesn't work as expected. (Mac OS - linux)

Is there any equivalent to os.chdir()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

# Create a directory
directoryName = raw_input('Enter new directory name: ')
cmdToExecute = 'mkdir ' + directoryName
print cmdToExecute
os.popen(cmdToExecute)

# Change Directory
directoryPath = os.getenv('PWD')
directoryPath = directoryPath + '/' + directoryName 
os.chdir(directoryPath)
```

Comment: You are not changing to directoryPath but trying to cmdToExecute

Comment: As a side comment, there's also `os.mkdir`, if you wanted to avoid calling an external `mkdir` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
os.chdir(cmdToExecute)
```

with:

```
os.chdir(directoryPath)
```

you can use `os.path.join` for joining paths:

```
directoryPath = os.path.join(directoryPath, directoryName)
```

this is working fine on my system:

```
import os
import sys

# Create a directory
directoryName = raw_input('Enter new directory name: ')
cmdToExecute = 'mkdir ' + directoryName
print cmdToExecute
os.popen(cmdToExecute)

# Change Directory
directoryPath = os.getenv('PWD')
directoryPath = os.path.join(directoryPath, directoryName)
os.chdir(directoryPath)
print os.getcwd()
```

output:

```
Beagle:titanic_machine_learning kumarshubham$ python test.py
Enter new directory name: test
mkdir test
/Users/kumarshubham/titanic_machine_learning/test
```

Comment: sorry. I am using os.chdir(directoryPath)

Comment: Are you running these commands on windows or mac. Because i am facing problem only with mac

Comment: i am running on my mac